# I installed pwndbg, but there's an error like this. how to solve this error?

Tags: python, linux

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/bin/python3.9 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-u912dbe1/psutil/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-u912dbe1/psutil/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-p5i4uxad                                                                                                                                                                                          
       cwd: /tmp/pip-install-u912dbe1/psutil/                                                                                                                                                      
  Complete output (45 lines):                                                                                                                                                                      
  running bdist_wheel                                                                                                                                                                              
  running build                                                                                                                                                                                    
  running build_py                                                                                                                                                                                 
  creating build                                                                                                                                                                                   
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9                                                                                                                                                              
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psutil                                                                                                                                                       
  copying psutil/_pswindows.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psutil                                                                                                                                
  copying psutil/_pslinux.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psutil                                                                                                                                  
  copying psutil/_common.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psutil                                                                                                                                   
  copying psutil/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psutil                                                                                                                                  
  copying psutil/_psposix.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psutil                                                                                                                                  
  copying psutil/_psosx.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psutil                                                                                                                                    
  copying psutil/_pssunos.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psutil                                                                                                                                  
  copying psutil/_compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psutil                                                                                                                                   
  copying psutil/_psaix.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psutil                                                                                                                                    
  copying psutil/_psbsd.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psutil                                                                                                                                    
  creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psutil/tests                                                                                                                                                 
  copying psutil/tests/test_system.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psutil/tests                                                                                                                   
  copying psutil/tests/__main__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psutil/tests                                                                                                                      
  copying psutil/tests/test_posix.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psutil/tests                                                                                                                    
  copying psutil/tests/test_memleaks.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psutil/tests                                                                                                                 
  copying psutil/tests/test_process.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psutil/tests                                                                                                                  
  copying psutil/tests/test_connections.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psutil/tests                                                                                                              
  copying psutil/tests/test_bsd.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psutil/tests                                                                                                                      
  copying psutil/tests/test_linux.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psutil/tests                                                                                                                    
  copying psutil/tests/test_osx.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psutil/tests                                                                                                                      
  copying psutil/tests/test_testutils.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psutil/tests                                                                                                                
  copying psutil/tests/test_aix.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psutil/tests                                                                                                                      
  copying psutil/tests/test_unicode.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psutil/tests                                                                                                                  
  copying psutil/tests/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psutil/tests                                                                                                                      
  copying psutil/tests/test_contracts.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psutil/tests                                                                                                                
  copying psutil/tests/test_misc.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psutil/tests                                                                                                                     
  copying psutil/tests/test_windows.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psutil/tests                                                                                                                  
  copying psutil/tests/test_sunos.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psutil/tests                                                                                                                    
  copying psutil/tests/runner.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.9/psutil/tests                                                                                                                        
  running build_ext                                                                                                                                                                                
  building 'psutil._psutil_linux' extension                                                                                                                                                        
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9                                                                                                                                                             
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/psutil                                                                                                                                                      
  x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -DPSUTIL_POSIX=1 -DPSUTIL_SIZEOF_PID_T=4 -DPSUTIL_VERSION=573 -DPSUTIL_LINUX=1 -I/usr/include/python3.9 -c psutil/_psutil_common.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.9/psutil/_psutil_common.o                                                                                                                                 
  psutil/_psutil_common.c:9:10: fatal error: Python.h: There are no such files or directories.                                                                                                          
      9 | #include <Python.h>                                                                                                                                                                      
        |          ^~~~~~~~~~                                                                                                                                                                      
  compilation terminated.                                                                                                                                                                          
  error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1                                                                                                                           
  ----------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                         
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for psutil
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this error like you and i installed python3.9-dev by using command `sudo apt install python3.9-dev`. It worked for me.